# Using CASE WHEN condition in PostGIS?

Tags: postgis, sql, postgresql-9.6

I'm trying to assign weights based on intersection of two layers. Below is my query

```
SELECT count(*), -- total number of grids in a postcode
       CASE WHEN st_intersects(centroids.geom, urban.geom)
            THEN 0.90::NUMERIC / count(*)
            -- when there is an intersection, 90% weights is equally divided among ALL the intersected grids
            ELSE 0.10 / count(*)
            -- When no intersection, 10% weights is equally divided among non intersected grids
       END  AS Weights
  FROM vrg.gfk_2016_id_5_digit_pcd_areas2013_projected AS postcodes,
       vrg.rdsid86_quadgrid                            AS fishnet,
       vrg.rdsid_86_quadgrid_centroids                 AS centroids,
       vrg.rdsid86_katrisk_poly_projected              AS urban
 WHERE fishnet.gid = centroids.gid 
   AND postcodes.id = '66371'
 GROUP BY centroids.geom, urban.geom
```

The query takes long time to run. How can I modify so that I can create a new table with vrgid and the correspong weights?

Comment: do you have duplicate geometries in centroids or urban? If no, it would be much more efficient to group by IDs rather than by geometries

Comment: a query performance question is always incomplete without the `explain analyze` output.

Comment: Maybe try to use bounding boxes first to check the intersection and speed up the query

Comment: time issue - make sure you have spatial indices created for all features involved